# Returning All Column Values From One Selection Within Column

Tags: parse-platform

What's the best approach in Parse to return all values of a column based on one item within that column being selected? For example:

```
Column 1          Column 2
___________________________
a        |       e
b        |       f
c        |       g
d        |       h
```

User selects "d" from a UI element, I want to have my app search through this entire class, pinponint "d" and then recognize it is in column 1, then return all values of that column.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the objects in column one and two stored in the same parse class?

Comment: the problem you are facing is to identify if the value the user choose is a unique one. can you say that there are no repeated values in all the columns?

Comment: Are you simply asking how to search for the object which contains "d" in "Column 1"?

Comment: Yuvi- correct, there will be no repeat values. The user supplies the input and then I need to search through that entire class and pinpoint which column that value is in so I can then return all values in that column

Comment: @user3803709 i think currently parse does not have such thing. You have to do it by using your logic.